# How to enable EAPOL forwarding through OpenVSwitch?

Tags: linux, networking, 802.1x

I'm trying to use OpenVSwitch to test 802.1x authentication, but it doesn't seem to be forwarding EAPOL multicast packets by default.

With a linux bridge, this would be done, say for bridge br0, by:

```
echo 8 > /sys/class/net/br0/bridge/group_fwd_mask
```

But for OpenVSwitch this path doesn't exist, [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuQHU.png) is what I see instead, where

- br0 is an OpenVSwitch
- br-left is a linux bridge

How to enable EAPOL forwarding through OVS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found what I was looking for:

Came across [this](https://techhub.hpe.com/eginfolib/networking/docs/switches/5130ei/5200-3946_security_cg/content/485048063.htm) post that listed the multicast address for EAPOL packets was fixed, which was consistent with what I was seeing.

Adding a flow for it allowed what was needed:

```
ovs-ofctl add-flow br0 "table=0, dl_dst=01:80:c2:00:00:03, actions=flood"
```